# Custom searches in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, search

I need to create multiple search fields that each search different content in WordPress. I know about [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/), which is helpful with specifying what is searched, but doesn't allow multiple, unique instances with their own search parameters.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about specific use cases?  Perhaps give us an example of how exactly you want these custom searches within custom contexts to perform?

Comment: Should have gone into more detail, you're right - basically, I have indexes (via page templates) for 3 custom content types, and a search field on each of those pages. I need those searches, however, to return only posts of that type. Therefore, it's three search fields with different search parameters, one post type each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom searching categories, you add a hidden input field to the search form, I'm sure there is a variation for content types.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="22" />
```

Possibly

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="your content type slug / name" />
```

Comment: That's EXACTLY the solution I was looking for, thank you, awats! One of those things difficult to search out online.